# Nested Queries not being called in MariaDB using nodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

This is my first project using MySQL and NodeJS, I am used to Mongo, so I might be doing something stupid here. Locally everything works fine (using MySQL) but when I deploy the following code to my hosting (that uses MariaDB) only the parent query inserts into the table (leads). The other table stays empty. Another issue is I don't have access to the NodeJS logs when it is deployed, but as far as I can tell the nested queries never get called.

```
var mysql     = require('mysql');

global.db     = mysql.createPool({
  host      : 'localhost',
  user      : 'client',
  password   : '******',
  database   : 'db'
});

router.post('/', function(req, res){
    const d     = req.body
    let subscribe = (d.subscribe ? 1 : 0)

    global.db.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        if (err) {
            res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
        } else {

                let lead    = [null, d.voornaam, d.achternaam, d.email, d.postcode, d.opmerkingen, d.soort, subscribe]
                let sql     = 'INSERT INTO leads VALUES ?';
            conn.query(sql, [[lead]], (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
                    conn.release();
                } else {
                    const lead_id = results.insertId
                    d.types.forEach(w => {
                        let wens = [null, lead_id, w.woningType, w.slaapkamers, w.prijs, w.oplevering]
                        let sql     = 'INSERT INTO wensen VALUES ?';
                        conn.query(sql, [[wens]], (err, results) => {
                            if(err) {
                                res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
                                conn.release();
                            }
                        })
                    })

                    res.end('True');
                    conn.release();
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you display the generated `INSERT` statements?

Answer (score 0):

Check syntax.  Note parens:

```
'INSERT INTO leads VALUES (?)'
```

Did this fail to tell you that?

```
if (err) { res.end(JSON.stringify(err)); ... }
```

Comment: Yes, the `res.end` message did not tell me that, also the data gets inserted to the leads table fine, it is the other table that is causing the problems. I did went back into my code and added the parens but it made no difference.